# Azure DevOps Yaml file location

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When a pipeline is created it must be specified its file path and branch. When this pipeline runs a branch is asked again. What is the purpose of this second branch? My initial thought was that the branch where my code is located and the branch where the Yaml file is located are two different things.

However, it seems, after some issues, that when I select a branch in the Run pipeline dialog both the Yaml file and the source code are checked out from this same branch. Is it correct?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior.

In Azure Devops, the location of the Yaml file is in the branch of the repo, so thehe executed yaml file and the source branch are synchronized.

The first operation of selecting a branch is used to create the pipeline, if you run directly for the first time, you don’t need to choose the execution branch.

When you run a DevOps pipeline(select execution branch), you choose a branch to execute the pipeline. The Yaml file in that branch is the one that will be executed by default and the pipeline will checkout the source code from the same branch.

The version that gets executed will be determined by which branch you're running the pipeline for.

If you want to checkout the source files of other branches in a yaml file, you need to add an [additional repo source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-repositories).

For example:

```
resources:
  repositories:

  - repository: TestRepo
    ref: refs/heads/branchname
    type: git
    name: Projectname/RepoName
    
stages:
- stage: deploy
  jobs:
  - job: test
    steps:
    - checkout: TestRepo
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, Kevin!